# Creating/Updating Sequences - MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, database

I have created a 'sequence' collection. It has 'name' and 'counter' fields. The 'name' field is set to 'Tag' and 'counter' field is set to 0. Following is the code within a method that returns the next value of 'counter' field.

```
final Sequence tagSequence = mongoTemplate.findAndModify(
  new Query(Criteria.where("name").is("Tag")), 
  new Update().inc("counter", 1), 
  new FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(true), Sequence.class);
```

However, this piece of code does not work. Any inputs?

I found an implementation for this here, http://dev.bubblemix.net/blog/2011/04/auto-increment-for-mongodb-with-the-java-driver/, however, I wanted to know what is wrong with this piece of code.

Comment: Can you increase the log level on the mongod server (e.g. mongod -vvv) and check what's actually being sent to the server when this code is executed?

Comment: I executed the pure java driver code that you linked to and see this in the logs running mongod -v:

Wed Jun 20 19:41:33 [conn3] run command test.$cmd { findandmodify: "seq", query: { _id: "seq1" }, update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } }, new: true, upsert: true }
Wed Jun 20 19:41:33 [conn3] query test.seq query: { _id: "seq1" } ntoreturn:1 idhack:1 reslen:48 0ms
Wed Jun 20 19:41:33 [conn3] update test.seq query: { _id: "seq1" } update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } } idhack:1 0ms

Comment: I didn't quite understand from these logs what exactly is going on.

Comment: The code that you linked works properly, and the logs show what is happening on the server.  You should compare this with what you see in the logs when you run your code, to determine what the difference is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works correctly provided that you have first saved the Sequence object, with the "Tag" name, in MongoDB. I'd suggest you annotate the `name` field with the `@Id` annotation. Ex.:

```
public class Sequence {
    @Id
    protected final String name;
    protected Long counter;

    public Sequence(String name, Long counter) {
        this.name = name;
        this.counter = counter;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public Long getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
    public void setCounter(Long counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

}
```

Save the object in MongoDB:

```
template.save(new Sequence("Tag",0L))
```